# Filter XML SQL query result

Tags: sql, xml, enums, db2

I have an XML column:

```
<xmlList> 
   <XMLEntity> 
      <sug>ACHR</sug>
   </XMLEntity>

  <XMLEntity> 
      <sug>DOA</sug>
   </XMLEntity>
</xmlList>
```

The `sug` can hold only a enum memeber(`ACHER` or `DOA`). I would like to check if there is a `sug` without one of these values.

In this way I get the `sug` node where **they are not** from enum values:

```
SELECT XMLSERIALIZE(XMLQUERY ('//xmlList/XMLEntity/sug[.!="ACHER" and .!="DOA"]'  
passing KTOVET ) as char large object) as XXX

FROM "TABLE"
```

The result is OK, but wherever the `sug` **is** `ACHER` or `DOA` I get empty line. How can I avoid the empty lines from result?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter data, then it should be a `WHERE` clause, not a projection list:

```
SELECT ...
FROM "TABLE" 
WHERE XMLSERIALIZE(XMLQUERY ('//xmlList/XMLEntity/sug[.!="ACHER" and .!="DOA"]'  
passing KTOVET ) as char large object) != '' -- or whatever comparison you need here
```

<strike>But I would recommend using [`xml.nodes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) method instead.</strike> D'oh obviously not on DB2.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot compare `char large object` to `!=''`. Any ideas?